# How to connect remotely to MongoDB on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, azure, azureportal

I created virtual machine (HPC Pack 2012 R2 on Windows Server 2012 R2) on Azure Portal, than I installed there MongoDB and create database and collections. After it I wrote some small C# console application, where I want to connect to my database. But I can't do it. I can't connect to the remote server.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 4):

So on Windows, all inbound TCP ports are closed by default. Try running the netsh on your Windows machine where the Mongo DB server is running.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open mongod port 27017" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=27017
```

See [Configure Windows Firewall for Mongo DB](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/configure-windows-netsh-firewall/) for details.

If you need to learn how to configure MongoDB, I would start here: [Mongo DB Configuration Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#use-the-configuration-file)

Also, I read somewhere that if you plan to use authentication, that you should make sure that the log files are saved to a different location than your data files and the configuration file. This is unverified however.

Answer (score 1):

If you can connect to that MongoDB locally, but not from remote location, probably you didn't open (at firewall) that mongodb port (27017).

Second possibility is that, that in your mongod config, you set that mongod answers only to localhost 127.0.0.1 and not outside interface.

Comment: how can I change mongod config file? There isn`t any config file at MongoDB directory (C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin).

Comment: [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb-community-edition). When you installed your mongo, you told system where to find that config file.